# Setting onclickListener on ImageView to view enlarged image

Tags: java, android, android-imageview

In my app I have a button which opens camera and captures image.When I capture the image I set it in ImageView.
I want to add a feature like whatsapp profile pics like when I click on the image it enlarges.
For that I have set an `onclicklistner` to the ImageView and defined a dialog.

```
imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view)
            {
                Dialog imagedialog = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
                imagedialog.setContentView(R.layout.imagedialog);
                ImageView photo = (ImageView) imagedialog.findViewById(R.id.photoenlarge);

            }
        });
```

In that dialog I have a ImageView which will show the enlarged image.

My camera code:

```
btncapture.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view)
            {
                Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                startActivityForResult(cameraIntent,CAMERA_REQUEST);
            }
        });
```

Code of `onActivityResult`:

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK)
        {
            Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
            imageView.setImageBitmap(photo);

        }
    }
```

In the `imageView.setOnClickListener` method how can I set `ImageView photo` with the captured image??

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using a dialog you can follow [this guide](https://developer.android.com/training/animation/zoom.html) from the android docs to do it.
What it does is having 2 imageviews on the same page, with the one showing the image at full size hidden, when clicking on the small one, the big one is shown with an animation.

Answer (score 0):

You have to something like this

```
imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view)
            {
                Dialog imagedialog = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
                imagedialog.setContentView(R.layout.imagedialog);
                ImageView photo = (ImageView) imagedialog.findViewById(R.id.photoenlarge);

          // get the applied image from the imageview as a bitmap

               Bitmap image=((BitmapDrawable)imageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();

           // set bitmap image to dialog image view
           photo.setImageBitmap(image);
          imagedialog.show();

            }
        });
```